# decimal to hex conversion in C

Tags: c, hex, decimal

I need to conver decimal numbers to 4 digit lower-case hex numbers prefixed by *0x*.
"%X" is good enough, but this is not exactly what I want.

```
printf("hex num is: %X\n", num);
```

Comment: Well, if it's not that then what is it that you "exactly want"?

Comment: Could you explain the difference between what you want and printing with format string "0x%04x"? Since you already know about %X, how about looking around the documentation of that to see if similar options are exactly what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you need either `0x%04x` or `%#06x`.

- `%x` means lower-case hex.
- `0` means padding with zeros if shorter than the specified number of digits.
- `4` or `6` specifies the desired width.
- `#` means `0x` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Is `printf("hex num is  : 0x%.4x\n", num);` what you want?

Comment: @Paul R: Certainly is, didn't know about '#'.

Answer (score -1):

Use `printf("hex num is  : 0x%x\n", num);`.